# Who is there? vs Who are there?

Tags: pronouns, subject-verb-agreement

I would like to know why 'Who is there?' is correct and why we can't use 'Who are there?' even if we know there is more than one person.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+are+there%2C+who+is+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20are%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

Who is used as a singular or a plural pronoun.  If you use the  who as an interrogative pronoun for a person, it takes a singular verb. If you use it for more than a person, it generally takes a singular verb, though the use of a plural verb is not ungrammatical.  So both the following sentences are correct.

Who is there.

Who are there.